# Better way of improving parallel bitonic sort

Tags: c++, sorting, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to improve my existing bitonic sort by reducing its executaion time and it works for some cases but not all of them. For example for small arrays with a size of like 20, the optimized time is better, but for large arrays with sizes of 10,000+ they end up having the exact same execution time half of the time and the other half the optimized version is faster. This is what I have:
**`Nthreads`** was declared globally and equals **`4`**.

```
void parallel_bitonicSort(int a[], int low, int cnt, int dir)            
{
    if (cnt > 1)
    {
        int k = cnt/2;
        omp_set_nested(1);  
        #pragma omp parallel sections 
        {
            #pragma omp section
                parallel_bitonicSort(a, low, k, 1);     // sort in ascending order since dir here is 1
            #pragma omp section
                parallel_bitonicSort(a, low + k, k, 0); // sort in descending order since dir here is 0
        }
        bitonicMerge(a, low, cnt, dir);                 // Will merge whole sequence in ascending order since dir=1. 
    }
}

void Opt_parallel_bitonicSort(int a[], int low, int cnt, int dir) // optimized version
{
    if (cnt > 1)
    {
        int k = cnt/2;
        omp_set_nested(1);  
        #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(Nthreads)    
        {
            #pragma omp section        
                Opt_parallel_bitonicSort(a, low, k, 1);   
            #pragma omp section       
                Opt_parallel_bitonicSort(a, low + k, k, 0);   
        }
        bitonicMerge(a, low, cnt, dir);   
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above only works if the input is a power of 2. Is that a general limitation of bitonic sort?

Comment: @user3666197 - Hello, hello. Come in please.

Answer (score 1):

As written, every recursive call spawns two new threads, so the number of threads increases exponentially. [omp_set_nested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/omp-set-nested)

You need to arrange to call the parallel version only at the top levels of recursion. I suspect you want to spawn only Nthreads-1 new threads. If you would post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could fix it.